# Create a fake "\meaning" (verbatimized) for content stored in seq?

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

I'm trying to create a command that represents the code that is stored in a sequence without executing it (something like `\meaning`)
. When using `\cs_log:N \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl` I get in the `.log` the content recorded in `scontents` environment before passed to `seq`.

Can I create a command like `\typestored[number]{seqname}` that gives me the same result in the document?

Which when run `\typestored[1]{contents}` take content *stored in the sequence* and shows in document:

```
Using \verb+scontents+ env no \verb+[key=val]+, save in \verb+contents+ 
with index $1$\footnote{AND footnotes !!}.%

Prove new \Verb*{ new fvextra whit braces } and environment \verb+Verbatim+

\begin{Verbatim}
(A) verbatim environment                                               %
many space here and percent at end of line                             %
                                many space                   
\end{Verbatim}
No espace after, see \verb+https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460967/7832+.\par
Use \verb|\relax|.\relax
```

I've tried to use :

```
% Fake \meaning
\tl_const:Nn \c_catcode_specials_tl { \  \\ \{ \} \$ \& \# \^ \_ \% \~ }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_catcode_dospecials:
  {
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \c_catcode_specials_tl
      {
        \char_set_catcode_other:N ##1
      }
  }

\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \typestored }{ O{1} m }
  { 
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
      {
      \_catcode_dospecials:
      \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { #1 }{ #2 }
      }
    \tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
  }
```

But it doesn't work, I just want the representation of what's kept in the `verbatim` *style*, `\l_tmpb_tl` does not contain content that is stored in the sequence. 
This is my **MWE**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}[2019/04/20]
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fvextra} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl }

\keys_define:nn { scontents }
  {
    save-env  .tl_set:N   = \l_scontents_name_seq_tl,
    save-env  .initial:n  = contents,
    show-env  .bool_set:N = \l_scontents_show_env_bool,
    show-env  .initial:n  = false  
  }

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215571/7832
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_scontents_append_contents:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      {
        \seq_new:c { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_item:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } { #1 }
  }

\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand{\getstored}{ O{1} m }
  {
    \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

% Define scontents (wrap \filecontentsdefmacro) whit [key=val] Delaying
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487746/7832
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{ scontents }{}
  {
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
    \scontents_start_environment:w
  }
  {
    \scontents_stop_environment:
    \scontents_atend_environment:
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_environment_keys:w [#1]
  {
    \keys_set:nn { scontents } { #1 }
  }

% Star environment
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
\cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_start_environment:w #1 ^^M
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 } { \scontents_environment_keys:w #1 }
    \group_begin: % open group for env
    \use:c { filecontentsdefmacro } { \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl } ^^M 
  }
\group_end:

% Stop environment
\cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_stop_environment:
  {
    \endfilecontentsdefmacro 
    \group_end:  % close group for env
  }

% A variant to replace \^^M for \^^J (need by Verb{..} from fvextra)
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8971/7832
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nxx } 

% Expand \l_tmpa_tl and pass to seq
\cs_gset_protected:Nn \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
  { 
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \^^M } { \^^J } \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl
    \cs_log:N \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl
    \exp_args:NNx \_scontents_append_contents:nn \l_scontents_name_seq_tl 
      {
       \exp_not:N \scantokens \exp_after:wN { \tl_use:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl} } %
      }
  }

% Code after scontent environment \seq_item:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } { #1 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_atend_environment:
  {
    \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
    \bool_if:NT \l_scontents_show_env_bool
      {
        \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { -1 }{ \l_scontents_name_seq_tl }
      }
    \cs_undefine:N \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl
  }

% Fake \meaning
\tl_const:Nn \c_catcode_specials_tl { \  \\ \{ \} \$ \& \# \^ \_ \% \~ }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_catcode_dospecials:
  {
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \c_catcode_specials_tl
      {
        \char_set_catcode_other:N ##1
      }
  }

\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \typestored }{ O{1} m }
  { 
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
      {
      \_catcode_dospecials:
      \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { #1 }{ #2 }
      }
    %\tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section*{Test environment}
Test \verb+\begin{scontents}+ no \verb+[key=val]+\par

\begin{scontents}
Using \verb+scontents+ env no \verb+[key=val]+, save in \verb+contents+ 
with index $1$\footnote{AND footnotes !!}.%

Prove new \Verb*{ new fvextra whit braces } and environment \verb+Verbatim+

\begin{Verbatim}
(A) verbatim environment                                               %
many space here and percent at end of line                             %
                                many space                   
\end{Verbatim}
No espace after, see \verb+https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460967/7832+.\par
Use \verb|\relax|.\relax
\end{scontents}

\section*{Show stored contents}
XX\getstored[1]{contents}NO space here :)\par

\section*{typestored}
%\typestored[1]{contents} % not work
\end{document}
```

If I remove the comments from `\tl_show:l \l_tmpb_tl` and `\typestored[1]{contents}` I get in `log` file:

```
\l_tmpb_tl=\_catcode_dospecials: \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {1}{contents}
```

As @David Carlisle put in his comment, which is not what I want. I hope it contains :

```
\l_tmpb_tl=Using \verb+scontents+ env no \verb+[key=val]+, save in
\verb+contents+
with index $1$\footnote{AND footnotes !!}.%

Prove new \Verb*{ new fvextra whit braces } and environment \verb+Verbatim+

\begin{Verbatim}
(A) verbatim environment                                               %
many space here and percent at end of line                             %
                                many space
\end{Verbatim}
No espace after, see \verb+https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460967/7832+.\par
Use \verb|\relax|.\relax
```

The author of the package provides the macro `\filecontentsprint` which I try to imitate using the content stored in the sequences. It should look something like this (or similar):

[image: Output Expected]

**EDIT 1**

A first attempt, by defining '\typestored' as follows:

```
\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \typestored }{ O{1} m }
  { 
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
      {
         \seq_item:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } { #1 }
      }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { ^ \c{scantokens} } { \c{#2[#1]} } \l_tmpb_tl 
    \tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \small\texttt{\meaning\l_tmpb_tl}
  }
```

I get:
[image: actual output]
which is almost exactly what I want, of course, breaks the title of the question (I don't need to modify catcode), I would need to replace `Ω` and `ΩΩ` with a `regex`(I don't know how). I hope this clarifies better what I want (my English is not the best, Spanish is my language).

**EDIT 2**

Second attempt, I copied the definition of `\filecontentsprint` from the style file and added the `newvbtm` package to avoid conflicts with the classic `verbatim` environment. It's not at all elegant and doesn't follow the line I'm looking for, the code is a bit "obfuscated" for me but it works.

```
% Fake \meaning, copy direct from filecontensdef package 
% Add \usepackage{newvbtm} to solve conflict whit verbatim nested
\newverbatim{typescverb}{}{}{}{}
\makeatletter
\gdef\filecontentsprint{\filecontentsdef@get\filecontents@print}%
\catcode`\^^M\active%
\gdef\filecontents@print #1{\let\filecontents@print@EOL^^M\let^^M\relax%
\begingroup\toks@\expandafter{#1}\edef\x{\endgroup%
\noexpand\begin{typescverb}^^M%
\the\toks@\@backslashchar end\string{typescverb\string}}\x^^M%
\filecontents@print@resetEOL}%
\gdef\filecontents@print@resetEOL{\let^^M\filecontents@print@EOL}%
\makeatother

\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \typestored }{ O{1} m }
  { 
    \group_begin: 
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
      { 
         \seq_item:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } { #1 }
      }
    \filecontentsprint\l_tmpb_tl
    \group_end:
  }
```

The output obtained is:
[image: output OK]

What I was looking for, of course, in doing this you lose the *spirit of using* `expl3` by mixing `LaTeX2e` code.

Greetings.

Comment: why can't you just use `\meaning` that will put essentially the same in the document as `\show` will show in the log? I must be missing something...

Comment: I think it's because of the use of `\scantokens`, the `filecontentsdef` package plays with `catcodes` in ways I don't understand and I can't get the result I'm hoping for.

Comment: it would help if you said what was wrong with the output of `\meaning` (`\meaning` returns all characters with catcode 12 or 10 so initial catcodes should not matter)

Comment: I think I have a problem with concepts, what I hope is that the output looks like the content is inside `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}`, I've played a little and get `"` instead of `\`, and other symbol...

Comment: `\texttt{\meaning\zzzzz}` should be the same except possibly you need to do something about line ends, but that is all.

Comment: I tried (I had read it from one of your answers) but, it didn't work for me, maybe I have misdeclared `\tl_put_right:`.

Comment: how did you make that first log block, if I uncomment the `\tl_show:N` in your code then it shows a completely different definition `\l_tmpb_tl=\_catcode_dospecials: \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {1}{contents}.`

Comment: You might also be interested in the functions provided by the `l3tl-analysis` package

Comment: Yes I have read a bit about `l3tl-analysis` but it's above my level, I think what I want can't be done with sequences. If I understood the documentation, `\seq_item:` is `\exp_not:n`, maybe I should switch to `l3prop` and use `\prop_get:cn` , but I've never used `l3prop`.

Comment: Looking a bit closer at your code, I don't think you can do only with *other* special characters. You need at least `^^M` and spaces to be active to map them to the correct output behavior. Also, `{filecontentsdefmacro}` should already give you *letter*-only characters, so the reassignment to *other* probably isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling this is an XY question. You cannot use `\scantokens` here if you are going to allow verbatim content inside the grabbed content if you then want the grabbed content to be used in normal typesetting: you have to go with the `beamer` approach of re-reading a temporary file.

Comment: I think I got it wrong, I edited the post and tried to clarify the idea.

Comment: If all you want is the detokenized content, then `\seq_get_right:NN \l_my_seq \l_my_tl` followed by `\tl_to_str:N \l_my_tl` will work.  I have a feeling you want more than that.

Comment: About your last comment, on the _spirit of `expl3`_: You are interfacing LaTeX3 code with a 2ε document and using 2ε packages. It's unlikely that you will get away without any 2ε code at all. The LaTeX3 kernel itself uses `\@currname`, `\input@path`, `\@filelist`, `\@unexpandable@protect`, etc., and that is after the 2ε--3 interface code is already set up. My point is: if the code is doing what you want it to, then you should leave it be. Of course you can do a direct translation of syntax, but you will still need to use `\filecontentsdef@get`. That or rewrite `filecontentsdef` in `expl3`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik : I understand that `2ε` cannot be completely dispensed with, but, one should try to follow the line proposed by `expl3`, that is, if something can be written in terms of `expl3` it should be done directly. Clearly I should use `\filecontentsdef@get` , I can try to make translation, something like `cs_gset_eq:N\myfcdefget \filecontentsdef@get` (which is quite simple), but, the macros used `\filecontentsprint` are harder to pass through (`\edef\x` for example), the code would be more readable (and nice). Rewrite `filecontentsdef` in `expl3` is absolutely out of my level :(

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Well, a complete rewrite of that bit of code is easy: https://pastebin.com/vppE2uUC. ``\catcode`\^^M\active`` becomes `\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M`, `\edef\x{...}\x` becomes `\use:x{...}`, and a few other changes... I also replaced the `\tl_put_right:Nx` by `\tl_set:Nx` because you weren't reusing the contents, so `set` is better.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik : Thank you very much, that's just what I had in mind, if you can turn it into an answer I'd appreciate it (I put a more chord title). I used the `newvbtm` package because I didn't find a way to use `fancyvrb` to define a new environment, if you can use this package better, but as it is working perfectly. All this is part of an "idea" I have in mind (https://pastebin.com/1s8tzC22). PD: A macro like a `\filecontentsdef@get` in `expl3` I'd be really pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems you are keen to follow the `expl3` guidelines, I suggest you take a look at [“The `expl3` package and LaTeX3 programming”](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) (`texdoc expl3`) and [“The LaTeX3 kernel: style guide for code authors”](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf) (`texdoc l3styleguide`). These are two short documents introducing the basic concepts of `expl3` and a preferable coding style.

That said, I translated the code in your question to `expl3` syntax and changed your code a bit to incorporate the guidelines above.

---

First, the translation of the code.
This answer is more conceptual than code, so I kept the `\newverbatim` thing as it was already working. As I said in the comment: you are interfacing LaTeX2ε with LaTeX3, so you will eventually have to put some 2ε in there, mainly if that code comes from a package. Since you are already using `\filecontentsdefmacro`, then I guess `\newverbatim` is fine.

I dropped `\makeatletter` (that’s yelling “I’m LaTeX2ε c@de!” :-). I made a copy of `filecontentsdef@get` to be used in `expl3` code with `\cs_new_eq:Nc`, so that you don't need to `\makeatletter`:

```latex
\cs_new_eq:Nc \__scontents_fcdef_get:NN { filecontentsdef@get }
```

Next, we make `^^M` active (inside a group) with:

```latex
\group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
```

Now comes the main macro. First, untangling the code a bit:

```latex
\gdef\filecontents@print#1{%
  \let\filecontents@print@EOL^^M%
  \let^^M\relax%
  \begingroup%
    \toks@\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{%
  \endgroup%
    \noexpand\begin{typescverb}^^M%
    \the\toks@%
    \@backslashchar end\string{typescverb\string}%
  }\x^^M%
  \filecontents@print@resetEOL%
}
```

First the code saves the definition of `^^M` and makes it a no-op with `\let^^M\relax`. We do the same:

```latex
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_fcdef_print:N #1
    {
      \cs_set_eq:NN \__scontents_fcdef_saved_EOL: ^^M
      \cs_set_eq:NN ^^M \scan_stop:
```

Notice that the scope of `\cs_new_protected:` is global, so `\gdef` is already covered. Also the function contains assignments, so it can't expand in expansion-only contexts, thus you need `protected`.

Now the code saves the expansion of a macro into `\toks@`, which is then used in an `\edef` with `\the\toks@`. This is used because `\the\toks@` expands only once, even inside an `\edef`, thus it allows one to use something like an ε-TeX `\unexpanded` in TeX (Actually it's the other way around: `\unexpanded{<stuff>}` does more or less `\toks@{<stuff>}\the\toks@` internally to prevent further expansion of `<stuff>`). The same can be accomplished with (in the `\edef`) `\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}`, without needing the `\toks@`. Since `expl3` (and LaTeX2ε, for that matter) requires ε-TeX anyway, there's no harm in that. A more `expl3`*y* version of that is `\exp_not:V #1`, which retrieves the contents of `#1` and prevents further expansion.

This bit of code also uses the `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup<stuff to be expanded>}\x`. This is precisely what an `x` expansion does in `expl3`, except that the grouping is not used because a private temporary macro is used. So we can just replace all that by `\use:x`.

Finally, the `\@backslashchar end\string{typescverb\string}` is replaced by the `expl3` equivalent string. Putting all that together:

```latex
      \use:x
        {
          \exp_not:N \begin{typescverb} ^^M
          \exp_not:V #1
          \c_backslash_str end \c_left_brace_str typescverb \c_right_brace_str
        }
        ^^M
```

Finally we reset `^^M` and end the group we started back there:

```latex
      \cs_set_eq:NN ^^M \__scontents_fcdef_saved_EOL:
    }
\group_end:
```

---

Now, some notes on the code in general.
In `expl3` there is a clear distinction of internal, code-level, and user-level functions and variables. User level is code defined with `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentCommand` and the like, which the final user will use in the document.

Code level functions and variables will be used in the implementation of the user level code and across different modules. These should be documented and they are named `\<module>_function_name:<args>` for functions and `\(l|g|c)_variable_name_<type>` for variables. Examples of these are `\seq_item:Nn` and `\l_tmpa_tl`, respectively.

Finally, internal code is used in the implementation and gory details of the former level. These functions should never be used outside the module they are defined in. These are named `\__<module>_macro_name:<args>` and `\(l|g|c)__variable_name_<type>`. Notice the double underscore in both cases. Examples of these are `\__seq_item:wNn` and `\l__char_tmp_tl`.

In your code you used many `\_scontents...`, which is midway between code-level an internal. You should decide: If you expect other programmers to use that then `\scontents...`, otherwise it is internal code and should be `\__scontents...`. The same goes for the variables.

You should also remeber to use the proper `\cs_new...` function. If the definition is expandable and you need it to be expandable, then you need `\cs_new:Npn` (or similars). In every other case the function should be defined with `\cs_new_protected:Npn` (or similar). `\__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn` uses `\seq_item:Nn` (which is expandable) to fetch contents from a `seq` variable. If you expect this function to expand in an `x`-type expansion you can't define it with `\cs_new_protected:Npn`, or it won't expand. Use just `\cs_new:Npn` here.

Remember also to use the proper variants depending on what type of argument you are passing to the function. Suppose you define a function, say, `\cs_new:Npn \my_use:n #1 { \use:c { my_#1_command_name: } }`, to use as `\my_use:n { funny }` and get `\my_funny_command_name:` (sorry for the dumb example), TeX allows you to do `\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { funny }` and then `\my_use:n { \l_my_tl }` because `\use:c` (`\csname`) expands `\l_my_tl` as it goes. But you should really *not* do that! In this particular case, no problem occurs. However suppose that now you want to disallow an empty argument to `\my_use:n`, then you define it with:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \my_use:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      { \msg_error:nn { mymodule } { empty-arg } }
      { \use:c { my_#1_command_name: } }
  }
```

If you use `\my_use:n { }` the error message is issued, but if you do `\tl_clear:n \l_my_tl` and then `\my_use:n { \l_my_tl }` the error will not show up! The correct way to use `\my_use:n` with `\l_my_tl` here would be `\exp_args:NV \my_use:n \l_my_tl` or simply `\my_use:V \l_my_tl` with the proper variant definition.

Somewhere you had `\cs_undefine:N \l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl`. That's *very* wrong! `\cs_undefine:N` should be used to make a `c`ontrol `s`equence undefined, but `\l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl` is a `t`oken `l`ist. Yes, it does work, and yes, a token list is, deep down, a control sequence, but it's conceptually wrong. A variable, once allocated with `\<type>_new:N` should exist “forever” and be reused accordingly. What you want here is probably `\tl_clear:N` to clear the contents of that token list.

The function `\_catcode_dospecials:` and the variable `\c_catcode_specials_tl` should be named `\__scontents_catcode_dospecials:` and `\c_scontents_catcode_specials_tl` because the module you are creating is `scontents`, not `catcode`. Note also that `expl3` defines a `seq` variable `\l_char_special_seq` which contains the special characters you need, so you *don't need* to define the sequence yourself, and can simplify the definition of `\__scontents_catcode_dospecials:` to:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_catcode_dospecials:
  { \seq_map_function:NN \l_char_special_seq \char_set_catcode_ignore:N }
```

but you aren't using it in the code, so I removed it.

You should only use `\ProvideDocumentCommand` and `\DeclareDocumentCommand` only when you have a good reason to. In all other cases you should stick to `\NewDocumentCommand` (Or `\RenewDocumentCommand` if redefining) to avoid surprises. Usually the “command already defined” error is helpful.

You should also avoid `\l_tmpa_tl` and other scratch variables defined by the LaTeX3 kernel. They can, of course, be used, but should be only in temporary code (if you are testing something, for example). If the code goes beyond temporary you should declare a variable and use that instead. This will avoid undesired interaction between packages which use the same scratch variable.

I also changed, in the definition of `\typestored`, `\tl_put_right:Nx` to `\tl_set:Nx` because you don't actually want to add to the existing contents of the token list. This would cause problems in longer stretches of code if you forgot to clear the token list (for example, if some other package code used `\l_tmpb_tl` and forgot to clear it, their contents would creep in your code).

---

To allow the usage of `fancyvrb` instead of `newvbtm` I had to change the timing of the `\scantokens` a tad. Apparently a verbatim environment like this:

```latex
\begin{typescverb}
\scantokens{<stuff>}
\end{typescverb}
```

(which is what the code was doing), defined with `newvbtm` will expand the `\scantokens` (somehow) and things will go as planned. However the same environment defined with `fancyvrb` does not, and it thinks the whole thing is just one line of code and typesets it as such. To have it working with `fancyvrb` you need to change to:

```latex
\scantokens{
  \begin{typescverb}
  <stuff>
  \end{typescverb}
}
```

However, to do that you need to remove the `\scantokens` from around the `<stuff>`, so I pass the token list variable to a `\__scontents_strip_scantokens:N` macro which expands the token list, checks if the first token is `\tex_scantokens:D`. If it is (that is, the token list is `\scantokens{<stuff>}`) then it expands to `\unexpanded{<stuff>}`. Otherwise it returns the token list unchanged.

---

After all that talking, here's your modified code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}[2019/04/20]
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__scontents_tmpa_tl
\keys_define:nn { scontents }
  {
    save-env  .tl_set:N   = \l__scontents_name_seq_tl,
    save-env  .initial:n  = contents,
    show-env  .bool_set:N = \l__scontents_show_env_bool,
    show-env  .initial:n  = false
  }
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215571/7832
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_append_contents:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      { \seq_new:c { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn #1#2
  { \seq_item:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \getstored } { O{1} m }
  { \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {#1} {#2} }
% Define scontents (wrap \filecontentsdefmacro) whit [key=val] Delaying
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487746/7832
\NewDocumentEnvironment { scontents } { }
  {
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
    \scontents_start_environment:w
  }
  {
    \scontents_stop_environment:
    \scontents_atend_environment:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_environment_keys:w [ #1 ]
  { \keys_set:nn { scontents } {#1} }
\group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_start_environment:w #1 ^^M
    {
      \tl_if_blank:nF {#1} { \scontents_environment_keys:w #1 }
      \group_begin: % open group for env
        \filecontentsdefmacro { \l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl } ^^M
    }
  \cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_stop_environment:
    {
        \endfilecontentsdefmacro
      \group_end: % close group for env
    }
\group_end:
\exp_args_generate:n { Vx }
\cs_gset_protected:Nn \__scontents_macro_to_seq:
  {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \^^M } { \^^J } \l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl
    \cs_log:N \l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl
    \exp_args:NVx \__scontents_append_contents:nn \l__scontents_name_seq_tl
      { \exp_not:N \tex_scantokens:D { \tl_use:N \l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl } }
  }
% Code after scontent environment \seq_item:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } { #1 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_atend_environment:
  {
    \__scontents_macro_to_seq:
    \bool_if:NT \l__scontents_show_env_bool
      { \exp_args:NnV \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { -1 } { \l__scontents_name_seq_tl } }
    \tl_clear:N \l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl
  }
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{typescverb}{Verbatim}{}
\cs_new_eq:Nc \__scontents_fcdef_get:NN { filecontentsdef@get }
\quark_new:N \q__scontents_strip_quark
\cs_new:Npn \__scontents_strip_scantokens:N #1
  { \exp_args:NV \__scontents_strip_scantokens:n #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \__scontents_strip_scantokens:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
      {
        \__scontents_if_scantokens:NwTF #1 \q__scontents_strip_quark
          { \exp_not:o { \use_ii:nn #1 } }
          { \exp_not:n {#1} }
      }
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__scontents_if_scantokens:Nw
  #1 #2 \q__scontents_strip_quark { TF }
  {
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \tex_scantokens:D #1
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }
\group_begin:
  \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_fcdef_print:N #1
    {
      \cs_set_eq:NN \__scontents_fcdef_saved_EOL: ^^M
      \cs_set_eq:NN ^^M \scan_stop:
      \use:x
        {
          \exp_not:N \tex_scantokens:D
            {
              \exp_not:N \begin{typescverb} ^^M
              \__scontents_strip_scantokens:N #1
              \c_backslash_str end \c_left_brace_str typescverb \c_right_brace_str ^^M
            }
        }
      \cs_set_eq:NN ^^M \__scontents_fcdef_saved_EOL:
    }
\group_end:
\NewDocumentCommand { \typestored } { O{1} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \tl_set:Nx \l__scontents_tmpa_tl
        { \seq_item:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } {#1} }
      \__scontents_fcdef_get:NN \__scontents_fcdef_print:N \l__scontents_tmpa_tl
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\section*{Test environment}
Test \verb+\begin{scontents}+ no \verb+[key=val]+\par

\begin{scontents}
Using \verb+scontents+ env no \verb+[key=val]+, save in \verb+contents+ 
with index $1$\footnote{AND footnotes !!}.%

Prove new \Verb*{ new fvextra whit braces } and environment \verb+Verbatim+

\begin{Verbatim}
(A) verbatim environment                                               %
many space here and percent at end of line                             %
                                many space                   
\end{Verbatim}
No espace after, see \verb+https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/460967/7832+.\par
Use \verb|\relax|.\relax
\end{scontents}

\section*{Show stored contents}
XX\getstored[1]{contents}NO space here :)\par

\section*{typestored}
\typestored[1]{contents} % not work
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and clarification of concepts, in my mind `\l__scontents_macro_tmp_tl` became `\cs` as I went through `\filecontentsdefmacro`. Now I will be able to adapt it to the idea I have in mind, which is to put together a small package (that's why `\ProvideDocumentCommand`) for a future _feature request_ to the `LaTeX3` team. Greetings

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL As I said, deep down a `tl` is just a macro. Roughly speaking `\tl_set:Nn \l__my_tl {hello}` does `\def\l__my_tl{hello}`, so `\cs_undefine:N` does what it advertises and it works in `\filecontentsdefmacro`. And that's one of the problems with interfacing stuff: trying not to mess up data types. However the whole purpose of variables is to be declared once and used throughout the code for the same data type, akin to a variable in other programming languages, so you should never undefine them, only clear. Good luck with your package!

Comment: With this answer, I think I can finish with my idea, I think I have clarified all my doubts and I can finish writing a package with dignity :). I will read with more attention `l3styleguide`. Greetings

Comment: Hi, I tried to adapt your answer using `fancyvrb` package (which I use in a regular way) by placing `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{typescverb}{Verbatim}{}`, but don't respect `^^M` and keep looking `[opt arg]` and you can't prevent the error. If you have some time, could you extend your answer by adding this? Greetings

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Hello, Pablo. Sorry for the delay, I could only look at it now. I changed the code a bit to make it work with `fancyvrb`. Apparently `fanvyvrb` does things in a different order than `newvbtm` and the `\scantokens` stored in the token list doesn't get expanded. I changed the code to remove the `\scantokens` initially used for typesetting, and then inserted an outer `\scantokens` that goes around the entire verbatim environment and it _seems_ to work. See if it works; if it does I'll change the answer. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/Cx6Jvg4X

Comment: It works perfectly, I can even use `\fvset{numbers=left}' . You can explain how the `\__scontents_strip_scantokens:` (apparently that's the magic line)

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL `\__scontents_strip_scantokens:N` just removes the `\tex_scantokens:D` from the token list so that it doesn't appear twice. I edited the answer.

Comment: The query was for the following, when using `\__scontents_strip_scantokens:N` this assumes that the content being extracted from the sequence starts with `\tex_scantokens:D` which is correct when using the `{scontents}` env, but in my original project I have a command like `\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \Scontents }{ +m } { \__scontents_append_to_seq:nn { \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl } {#1} }` which doesn't need `\tex_scantokens:D`. Can `\__scontents_strip_scantokens:` be modified to work in this case? (Promise this is the last query). Once again thank you for the time invested.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL The code actually tested if the first token in `#1` was `\tex_scantokens:D`. However it was a bit of a lazy code and would have undesired side effects in certain circumstances (if `#1` contained only one token it would break, if `#1` was something like `{some}{thing}` it would strip braces: `something`, and a couple other issues). I adopted a more conservative approach and the code will only act (I hope) if the token list is `\scantokens{<stuff>}`. All other cases it remains as is. I didn't test because I don't have that macro, but if it doesn't work, call me! :-)

Comment: Thanks Phelype, I tried your solution but it doesn't work with my version, the strange thing is that in your first answer with the `newverb` package if I could do it, I leave the example code here (https://pastebin.com/bBTJ8uAd) so you can check it when you have some time. Greetings

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Here you go: https://pastebin.com/NzgBZy05 I put some comments in the file (I marked them with my name so that you can find them easily). There were a couple of problems, most notably the value of `save-cmd` being empty (then you got an `empty verbatim` error), and a missing `^^M` which would make one-line contents break. I think it's all working fine now :-) I also added a few more notes to my answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again, but, I have a new question (it's a bit confusing and the code very long) related to the same code. I'm trying to pass a macro given by Ulrich Diez at (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472044/7832) but it's written in pure `TeX` and I don't know how to adapt it to `expl3`. The current code is (https://gist.github.com/pablgonz/678c3d16909078cc6603946409458f81), it is quite long for the test as it is the complete idea I had in mind. If you have time and give me a hand with this, I would appreciate it very much.  Greetings once again.

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Hello Pablo! Sorry for the delay: I'm at my parents' since Thursday, and only today I got some time left to check on TeX.SX. Here's your code: https://pastebin.com/yckpyPH1. Most of the code is a direct 2e->l3 translation, so it's rather straightforward. I put some comments in the source for you. I haven't got the time yet to carefully read the code to see what it does: I think it can be optimized using `expl3`'s features. Again, I'm deeply sorry for the delay (you can find my email in the source of my EoTeX class (the link is in my profile), if you want to call me there :-).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, you can place your macro adaptation in (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500270/7832), I thought it was appropriate to ask a new question to confuse the topics. I'll add all the modifications you've given me, for now if you have more optimizations you can add, place them in this post. As soon as I have the complete written idea, I will send an email to know your opinion regarding the package I'm writing, if it can be useful for other users and meets the conditions of being well written could make it public. Saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Since Siracusa already posted a very good answer to your question, already with the optimizations I mentioned, I'll refrain to post a downgraded version of his answer; I'm sure you'll understand :-) About making your package public, I say: go for it. There isn't a peer-review system for packages uploaded to CTAN, so you can upload basically anything if you deem it worth it. (This explains some of the dubious packages which are on CTAN, but this is a talk for another day :-). If you want feedback I suggest you the LaTeX-L mailing list: more people will see it!