# Convert a macro from Latex2e to expl3

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

I'm trying to implement a `\Scontents` command inside a small package that behaves in two different ways:

```
\Scontents*[opt]<del>argument<del>
\Scontents[opt] { argument }
```

With the star it behaves like `\verb` and receives the delimited argument or with `{...}` that they are balanced.

Without the star it behaves like a regular command using `{...}`.

In both cases the `argument` is saved in a sequence and then used. 
The command works perfectly for what I want, the issue is that to implement it I have used a beautiful macro given by Ulrich Diez (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472044/7832) with an extensive explanation of how it works, but, I would like to know if you can migrate to a more `expl3` style code, the code is quite `obfuscated` for my level. This is the example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { scontents }
  {
    store-cmd .tl_set:N  = \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl,
    store-cmd .initial:n = contents,
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_append_contents:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      { \seq_new:c { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn #1#2
  { \seq_item:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
% From Ulrich Diez https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472044/7832
\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\UDEndlreplace[2]{\romannumeral0\@UDEndlreplace{#2}#1^^M\relax{}}%
  \newcommand*\@UDEndlreplace{}%
  \long\def\@UDEndlreplace#1#2^^M#3\relax#4#5{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}%
    { #5{#4#2}}{\@UDEndlreplace{#1}#3\relax{#4#2#1}{#5}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UDcollectverbarg[3]{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space the usual catcode so \UD@collectverbarg
                     %    cannot catch a space as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be caught:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be caught:
    \do\{ % <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[4]{%
  \do\ %             % <- Now that \UD@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
                     %    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space the
                     %    verbatim-catcode again.
  \catcode`\^^M=12   % <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#4{%
    \edef\@tempb{##1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UDEndlreplace\expandafter{\@tempb}{#1}{\def\@tempb}% <- this starts
                               %    the loop for replacing endline-characters.
    \expandafter\UD@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#2}{#3}% <- this "spits
                               %    out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[3]{%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
  #2{#3{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn % Back to |expl3| programing
\cs_new_eq:Nc \__scontents_UD_firstofone: { @firstofone }
\exp_args_generate:n { Vx }
\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \Scontents }{!s O{} }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \IfNoValueF {#2} { \keys_set_known:nn { scontents } {#2} }
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      { \UDcollectverbarg{^^J}{\__scontents_UD_firstofone:}{\__scontents_append_vercmd:n} }
      { \__scontents_append_stdcmd:n }
  }
% No starred
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_append_stdcmd:n #1
  { 
    \exp_args:NV  \__scontents_append_contents:nn \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl {#1}
    \group_end:
  }
% Starred
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_append_vercmd:n #1
  {
    \exp_args:NV \__scontents_append_contents:nn \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl { \tex_scantokens:D {#1} }
    \group_end:
  }
% get
\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand { \getstored } { O{1} m }
  { \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\Scontents[store-cmd=nostarred]{Using Scontents command, 
no verbatim suport, save in seq nostarred with index $1$.}

\Scontents*[store-cmd=starred]|Using \verb+\Scontents*+ command, 
delimited by tbar, save in seq starred with index $1$.
\begin{verbatim*}
      verbatim environment
\end{verbatim*}|

\noindent\hrulefill

\getstored[1]{nostarred}\par
\getstored[1]{starred}
\end{document}
```

Can this macro be written in terms of `expl3`? or is it better to leave it as it is, my idea is to try to leave the code in favor of `expl3` if possible.

Greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a pure `expl3` reimplementation. The most notable changes are:

- `\Scontents` now has argument types `O{} +v`. By using `xparse`'s verbatim argument type `v`, the use of the star isn't necessary anymore, as this type automatically detects if a braced argument or a delimiter character follows.
- The `\UDcollectverbarg` was removed, because it seems to do what the `v` type already does.
- `\tex_scantokens:D` is stored along with the verbatim text in the `\g__scontents_seq_name_*_seq` sequences and executed when the final sequence is queried. Also `\tex_newlinechar:D` is set to 13 there. I think this is essentially the same as the replacement of `^^J` by `^^M` that happened in your `\UDcollectverbarg` macro.

The full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { scontents }
  {
    store-cmd .tl_set:N  = \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl,
    store-cmd .initial:n = contents,
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_append_contents:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      { \seq_new:c { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } {#2}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_item:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } {#1}
  }

\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \Scontents }{ O{} +v }
  {
    \IfNoValueF {#1} { \keys_set_known:nn { scontents } {#1} }
    \exp_args:NV \__scontents_append_contents:nn \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl
      {
        \group_begin:
        \tex_newlinechar:D = 13 \scan_stop:
        \tex_scantokens:D { #2 }
        \group_end:
      }
  }
% get
\ProvideDocumentCommand { \getstored } { O{1} m }
  { \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {#1} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Scontents[store-cmd=nostarred]{Using Scontents command, 
no verbatim support, save in seq nostarred with index $1$.}

\Scontents[store-cmd=starred]|Using \verb+\Scontents*+ command, 
delimited by tbar, save in seq starred with index $1$.
\begin{verbatim*}
      verbatim environment
      with unbalanced } braces }
\end{verbatim*}|

\noindent\hrulefill

\getstored[1]{nostarred}\par
\getstored[1]{starred}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I've been a bit late (it's the end of the academic semester in my country). A query, you can move `\tex_newlinechar:D = 13`and `\tex_scantokens:D` into `\Scontents`, I think if possible I can adapt a project I have in mind. Greetings

Comment: Okay, I moved it back

Comment: Thanks again, it works perfectly.